# Confusing angle-chasing question

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

AB = BC = CD = DE = EF = FG = GA

Find angle GAB. 
Please, I want the correct answer. I know how to solve it, but I am getting confused by the number of triangles in it. I am getting different answer every time I solve it. Please tell the correct answer. Options:

a. 180/5
b. 60
c. 20
d. 180/7

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you set up equations for the angles and use the numerous isosceles triangles?

Comment: Ya, I can and have. But I am puzzled by the numerous equations, and getting a different answer everytime. I want the answer.

Comment: Then you should have noticed that if angle $GAB=x$, then angle $CDE=180-6x$, so first two options can be easily ruled out. And only working out the angles of the triangle will lead you nowhere. You need to investigate on the side lengths and probably use some trigonometry. Otherwise you will need some ingenuous construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $\angle gab=x$, then we have:
1. $\angle acb=x$ (since ab=bc)
2. $\angle gfa=x$ (since gf=ga)
3. $\angle ebd=2x$ (external angle of $\triangle$abc)
4. $\angle edb=2x$ (since bc=cd)
5. $\angle fge=2x$ (external angle of $\triangle$agf)
6. $\angle feg=2x$ (since ef=fg)
7. $\angle efd=3x$ (external angle of $\triangle$aef)
8. $\angle edf=3x$ (since ef=de)
9. $\angle edc=\angle edf-\angle cdb=x$
10. $\angle ecd=3x$ (external angle of $\triangle$acd)
11. $\angle ced=3x$ (since de=ed)
12. $\angle fed=\angle ced-\angle gef=x$

Finally, looking at sum of angles in $\triangle$def, we get:
$x+3x+3x=180$

Solve this to find $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the unknown angle at $a$ by $\alpha$. Working along the figure it is easy to express any occurring angle in terms of $\alpha$, using only that the angles at the base of an isosceles triangle are equal and that the sum of the three angles of any triangle is $\pi$. You will find angles $\alpha$,  $2\alpha$, $3\alpha$, $\pi-4\alpha$, and the like. Looking at the triangle $ade$ you will finally obtain an equation that can be solved for $\alpha$.

Comment: There comes the problematic part. If angle $EAD$ is $\alpha$, then angle $AED$ turns out to be $3\alpha$ and angle $ADE$ turns out to be $\pi-4\alpha$. We get a redundant equation.

Comment: @Abishanka Saha: By symmetry angle $ade$ is equal to angle $aed$. In fact $3\alpha=\pi-4\alpha$.